# orgDefine a keyboard binding that works only in org-agenda when under evil

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, evil, org-agenda

Using emacs 25.2.2 on Kubuntu 18.04 with evil and evil-org.

Here is a very basic question that I could not get a clear answer for, despite googling.

I want to define a keyboard binding that works ONLY in `org-agenda` when it is under `evil`.

I want to be able to press `C-s` to execute `save-all-org-buffers`.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with following code:

```
(evil-define-key 'normal org-agenda-mode-map
  (kbd "C-s") 'save-all-agenda-buffers)
```

Adjust first argument of `evil-define-key` to whatever evil `<state>` you are using for `org-agenda` buffers.

However I am not sure about `save-all-agenda-buffers` function - it doesn't exist in my Emacs with `org-mode` 9.1.3. If it doesn't exist in your Emacs either, I would suggest you to use `org-save-all-org-buffers` instead.

---

[noctuid/evil-guide](https://github.com/noctuid/evil-guide) is great help resource to look at when you setting up evil in Emacs

Comment: Thanks! But that does not work. I added that code to my `init.el`, did `evaluate-buffer`, went to my agenda and tried `C-s` It still does incremental search. I did `C-h k C-s` while in agenda. It shows incremental search as a command. Also, it is `org-save-all-org-buffers`. I have edited the question. Lastly, that is a great resource, indeed.

Comment: I figured out the error. At least in my case, agenda is displayed in motion state. So, I changed `'normal` to `'motion` and all is well now.